# Changing the X to a different color using Linear Gradient

Tags: html, css, colors, linear-gradients

I found this code, but I'm confused about how I would change the color of the X. Can someone show me how to? This is what I'm asking for help with.

And, am I required to use RGBA for this?

https://jsfiddle.net/58tfv09z/

If I am, then there's

**HEX to RGBA converter**

http://hex2rgba.devoth.com

and

**RGB to RGBA converter**

http://jsfiddle.net/wb5fwLoc/1/

```css
.crossed {
    width: 266px;
    height: 266px;
    border:  3px solid red;
    background: 
       linear-gradient(to top left,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
           rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
           rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),
       linear-gradient(to top right,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
           rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
           rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
```

```html
<div class="crossed"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses `linear-gradient` to display a line by setting other parts invisible, you can change the color by modifying the visible parts with `alpha channel = 1`:

```css
.crossed {
    width: 266px;
    height: 266px;
    border:  3px solid red;
    background: 
       linear-gradient(to top left,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
           rgba(0,255,0,1) 50%, /* put your rgb value here */
           rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
           rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),
       linear-gradient(to top right,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
           rgba(0,255,255,1) 50%,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
           rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="crossed"></div>
```

You can find more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

Comment: How would I change the background color?

Comment: How would I change the background to black? With the lines still showing?

Comment: You can set colors to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)` in the second linear-gradient except for the third one. To change the background, each pair (1st,2nd) (4th,5th) controls a range of color.

Comment: I did that I got it all black, but only one line was showing.

Comment: See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ouc98et6/). The parts of first linear-gradient should transparent otherwise the second one won't be shown. It's setting the background in bottom layer and put a single line in the top layer.